# Disabled button still listens to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a problem in a form where I do some jquery validations. If a specific input field is not filled out, it should disable a "step forward" button by adding a disabled attribute:

```
if errors
  $('.btn-move-forward').attr("disabled", true)
```

that works but I also have a click event on that button:
(coffeescript)

```
$('.btn-move-forward').click ->
  $('#step2, #step3').toggle()
```

I expect `.btn-move-forward` to not fire the click event when the button is disabled but it does!!

First: I don't understand why because every browser spec defines that this should not happen. Anyways, I tried to bypass it by doing the following stuff:

```
$('.btn-move-forward').click ->
  if !$(this).is(:disabled)
    $('#step2, #step3').toggle()
```

or this

```
$('.btn-move-forward').click ->
  if $(this).prop("disabled", false)
    $('#step2, #step3').toggle()
```

or combining the event listeners like this:

```
$('.btn-move-forward').on 'click', '.btn-move-forward:enabled', ->
   $('#step2, #step3').toggle()
```

No, all of this won't work properly. The button still behaves as a move-forward button.

All I want is the button not listening to `onclick` if it is disabled.

Comment: Is the `.btn-move-forward` element a `button` or `input type="button"`? If not, then the disabled attribute won't work. If it is one of those types, then your code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/pcokf7d8/. You need to check the console for errors and ensure that the `disabled` property is being applied as you believe it is.

Comment: That did it @RoryMcCrossan! It was a simple div before and making it a button element worked. If you reply it I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `disabled` property only applies to form elements. This means that unless the `.btn-move-forward` element is a `<button>` or `<input type="button">` then the `disabled` attribute will have no effect.

You can see a working example using a `button` here:

```js
$('.btn-move-forward').prop("disabled", true).click(function() {
  console.log('Moving forward...');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-move-forward">Move forward</button>
```

Comment: P.S: `.prop()` is best used for setting `disabled` or `checked` element properties

Comment: True :) Updated this old answer to include a snippet too

Comment: Thanks so much! I just found myself mistyped "button" as "btn"

Answer (score 4):

Change it to use `prop()` instead.

```
$('.btn-move-forward').prop("disabled", true)
```

Comment: But, not re-enable just doing .prop("disabled", false)

Answer (score 4):

Please off the click event

```
$('.btn-move-forward').off('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

**to disable:**

```
$('.btn-move-forward').prop("disabled", true);
```

**to re-enable:**

```
$('.btn-move-forward').removeClass('disabled'); // do this also.
$('.btn-move-forward').prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: This did not help for a link (A tag).

Answer (score 2):

I think, disabling `click` event is not a good idea. Because you have to enable `click` event again, if you enable the button.

For `disabled button`, I just `check disabled state`, if `disabled` `return`.

---

#### Html button:

```
<span class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-move-forward">Book</span>
```

---

#### How to disable button:

```
$('.btn-move-forward').addClass('disabled');
```

---

#### Click event:

```
$('.btn-move-forward').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) { 
    console.log('-- Button is disabled. Return from here. --');
    return false;
  }

  // write code for click event here
  $('#step2, #step3').toggle()
});
```

Comment: $('.btn-move-forward').addClass('disabled');
This did it for me.  I'm using a razor form with bootstrap, and this was the only method that actually disabled the button.

Answer (score 2):

you can try a porperty of almost tag: onclick="return false"

Answer (score 1):

use pointer-events:none; where you don't needed click events

```css
.btn[disabled]{pointer-events:none;}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener("click", e=>{
      alert(e.target.innerText)
    })
})
```

```css
.btn{
  display:inline-block;
  background: #3f51b5;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),
   0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
   0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 10px;
    min-width: 64px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Roboto","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    will-change: box-shadow;
    transition: box-shadow .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,1,1),background-color .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1),color .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;   
}

.btn[disabled]{pointer-events:none; opacity:0.5}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Clickable button</div>
<div class="btn">Clickable 2 button</div>
<div class="btn">Clickable 3 button</div>
<hr />
<div class="btn" disabled>Disabled button</div>
<div class="btn" disabled>Disabled 2 button</div>
<div class="btn" disabled>Disabled 3 button</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am too late by too many year :P
Still if someone can get help out of my answer:
HTML :

```
<button type="button" id="verifyBtn" class="disabled" onClick="submitForm(this);"></button>
```

JS:

- To enable

  `$j('#verifyBtn').addClass('disabled');`

  `$j('#verifyBtn').attr('disabled','disabled');`
- To disable

  `$j('#verifyBtn').removeClass('disabled');`

  `$j('#verifyBtn').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: dont u have this inverted... swop enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 0):

this is code work for me !!!
when btn disabled has a true click doesn't work and when btn disabled has a false click event work

```
//disabled btn in windows load or in desigen
$('#btnEdit').attr("disabled", true);
//in click function write this code
$('#btnEdit').click(function () {
        var isDisabled = $('#btnEdit').attr('disabled');
        if (!isDisabled) {
        //Write code here
        }
    });
```