# how do I programmatically disable kendo tabstrip button

Tags: kendo-ui

I cannot disable a tabstrip button. Ive tried the following running within the Tabstrips Activate event

tabButton.data("kendoButton").enable(false)

-- fails because the button isnt a kendo button

tabButton.addClass("disabled")

-- fails, disabled is added, but button is still usable

where tabButton was derived along the following lines, I know I gottten it.

var tabButton = $(".k-button")

I resolved the issue by adding a css & class as in

.disable_a_href { pointer-events: none; }

tabButton.addClass("disable_a_href")

Comment: You can disable a common button with jQuery like `tabButton.prop("disabled", "disabled")`...

Comment: just tried this, it didnt work  - but I did note the button is an anchor link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109771/disabled-button-still-listens-to-click-event

Answer (score 1):

TabStrip has explicit [enable](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/methods/enable) and [disable](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/methods/disable) functions.

If you want them to start disabled, use the class `k-state-disabled` on the `<li>` element.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3k27g4na/8/) showing both of these methods. Tab 2 will start disabled, and tab 3 can be toggled.

Answer (score 0):

To disable all tabstrip except the active you can use this code:

```
var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
tabStrip.enable(tabStrip.tabGroup.children().not(".k-state-active"), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a very simple approach ...

```
var tabstrip = $("#yourtabstripID").data("kendoTabStrip");
var tabContentID = $("content_div_of_that_tab").parent().attr('id');

//Enable tab item ...
tabstrip.enable(tabstrip.tabGroup.children("[aria-controls='" + tabContentID + "']")[0], true);

//Disable tab item ...
tabstrip.enable(tabstrip.tabGroup.children("[aria-controls='" + tabContentID + "']")[0], false);
```

I feel the code above is pretty self explanatory ...